# Linux-style window resizing

Tags: window-manager

Redhat Linux has this really nice feature where I can hold down the Window key, middle-mouse click-and-hold somewhere in a window, and drag to resize the window.  It doesn't have to be the very corner of the window.  The corner that is resized depends on which quadrant of the window I clicked in - for instance, if I middle-mouse clicked somewhere in the lower-left of the window, dragging would lock the upper-right of the window, but resize based on shrinking/growing the lower left.  Using the left click instead of the middle click can move the entire window (this can only be done on Mac OS X by grabbing the title bar).

I'm specifically only interested in these 2 features - are there any apps available that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Zooom/2 is the closest thing I could find so far.
Sadly, it's discontinued and hasn't been actively worked on since 2011.  It is $20 shareware.
The functionality is pretty close, however it doesn't allow you to use the middle- and right- click buttons as modifiers, so it's not possible to mimic Linux functionality, but it's close enough.

The other major drawback is that it doesn't work with Photoshop :(  I suspect this is Apple's fault, however.

Comment: The [website](http://coderage-software.com/zooom/index_green/index.html) indicates it's compatible to up Yosemite.

Comment: I love Zooom/2 and want to confirm that it works with El Capitan!